# Set text to textview returns null in android code

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, butterknife

I am trying to set a text for my textview every time I update the user interface.

```
public class CourseDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
  private static final String TAG = "CourseDetailsFragment";
  private OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;
  private static CourseDetailsFragment instance;
  protected @Bind(R.id.courseName)TextView courseName;
  Course c;
  View view;


public static CourseDetailsFragment getInstance(){
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new CourseDetailsFragment();
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_overview);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Course Detail"); //redundant?

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    listener = null;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        listener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course_details, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
public void updateUI(Course cData) {
    c = cData
    courseName.setText(cData.getName());
}
```

}

This where I am trying to set text for my textview. However `courseName` remains `null`.

```
public void updateUI(Course cData) {
    c = cData
    courseName.setText(cData.getName());
}
```

This is where updateUI gets called.

```
public void onDataEntry(boolean saved, Fragment fragment, String identifier,     Object T) {
    if (T instanceof Course){
        Course courseData = (Course)T;
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataEntry: " + courseData.getName() + " " + courseData.getGrade());
        CourseDetailsFragment.getInstance().updateUI(courseData);
    }
}
```

This is my stacktrace:

```
02-19 17:31:56.317 4689-4689/hsleiden.nl.barometer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: hsleiden.nl.barometer, PID: 4689
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at hsleiden.nl.barometer.views.fragment.CourseDetailsFragment.updateUI(CourseDetailsFragment.java:101)
                                                                     at hsleiden.nl.barometer.views.activity.BaseActivity.onDataEntry(BaseActivity.java:306)
                                                                     at hsleiden.nl.barometer.adapter.CourseAdapter$1.onClick(CourseAdapter.java:57)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: hola David, por favor postea el logcat

Comment: Can you provide the exception stack trace?

Comment: One of the most important skills as a Java programmer is locating errors and fixing them. The most important tool to help you with this is call a stacktrace. It gives you the file name and line number where the error occurs.

Comment: Does `fragment_course_details.xml` contain an element with the id `R.id.courseName`? If not, it **will be null**

Comment: Please, provide more context from where you are calling `updateUI`, since you are probably calling it before the fragment creates its view.

Comment: Where is the `updateUI()` method defined? In which class?

Comment: Where do i find the stacktrace? fragment_course_details.xml does have an element R.id.courseName

Comment: "I keep getting a null pointer exception" -- where do you see this NPE? thats were you should have stack trace too, in your logs?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, go to the "Android Monitor" window to find the stacktrace. It should be at the bottom of the main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
CourseDetailsFragment.getInstance().updateUI(courseData);
```

The thing is, your `@butterknife.Bind` annotated `TextView` will remain null until the call to `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)`. To make that call, you need a valid parent of your view hierarchy, which you can obtain no earlier than when `onCreateView` lifecycle method is called, hence the `TextView` is null until `onCreateView`. Now, `onCreateView` is called after `onCreate`, which in turn is called after `onAttach`, which is triggered by attaching the fragment to an `Activity`, usually through the use of `FragmentManager`. Calling `CourseDetailsFragment.getInstance().updateUI(courseData)` does not automatically trigger the fragment lifecycle, it only instantiates the `Fragment` instance, and as until that `Fragment` is attached to an `Activity` and `onCreateView` is called, your `courseName` is a null reference, which means that calling the `updateUi` method instantly after creation of the `Fragment` is doomed to result in a null pointer exception.

The only option that this line of code would work without throwing exception is if this `Fragment` had been previously instantiated, attached to an activity and it had gone through the `onCreateView` method.

For reasons described above, I don't recommend implementing fragments as singletons, especially if you want to make direct calls on a reference to such fragment from other components. Due to the lifecycles, Activities and Fragments are state machines in practice, and your `updateUi` method doesn't consider that state, which is the root of your problem.

For a **quick fix**, you can override the `onFragmentsResumed` method in your `Activity` - if the fragment was previously attached, your references should be valid at that point.